# jquery .on change live update in input field based on value selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

keyup function is working correctly.
Now i want is, after keyup function has perform the calculation, if i go ahead and change the select option, perform calculation based on the selected option without keying up again unless may be i want to change the amount.

thanks in advance.

please the is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/to5akqzn/)

```
  $('#buyselect').change(function() {

var value = $(this).val();
switch (value) {
  case 'btc':
    var rate = 4.7;
    var ngnrate = 5.7;

    var buyusd = $("#buyusd");
    buyusd.keyup(function() {
      var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyusd.val() * rate)) ? 0 : (buyusd.val() * rate);
      total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
      $("#buyghc").val(total1);

      var ngntotal = isNaN(parseInt(buyusd.val() * ngnrate)) ? 0 : (buyusd.val() * ngnrate);
      ngntotal1 = parseFloat(ngntotal).toFixed(2);
      $("#buyngn").val(ngntotal1);
    });

    var buyghc = $("#buyghc");
    buyghc.keyup(function() {
      var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyghc.val() / rate)) ? 0 : (buyghc.val() / rate);
      total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
      $("#buyusd").val(total1);

      var ngntotal = isNaN(parseInt(total1 * ngnrate)) ? 0 : (total1 * ngnrate);
      ngntotal1 = parseFloat(ngntotal).toFixed(2);
      $("#buyngn").val(ngntotal1);

    });

    var buyngn = $("#buyngn");
    buyngn.keyup(function() {
      var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyngn.val() / ngnrate)) ? 0 : (buyngn.val() / ngnrate);
      total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
      $("#buyusd").val(total1);

      var ghctotal = isNaN(parseInt(total1 * rate)) ? 0 : (total1 * rate);
      ghctotal1 = parseFloat(ghctotal).toFixed(2);
      $("#buyghc").val(ghctotal1);
    });
    break;

  case 'gcr':
    var rate = 7;
    var ngnrate = 3;

    var buyusd = $("#buyusd");
    buyusd.keyup(function() {
      var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyusd.val() * rate)) ? 0 : (buyusd.val() * rate);
      total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
      $("#buyghc").val(total1);

      var ngntotal = isNaN(parseInt(buyusd.val() * ngnrate)) ? 0 : (buyusd.val() * ngnrate);
      ngntotal1 = parseFloat(ngntotal).toFixed(2);
      $("#buyngn").val(ngntotal1);
    });

    var buyghc = $("#buyghc");
    buyghc.keyup(function() {
      var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyghc.val() / rate)) ? 0 : (buyghc.val() / rate);
      total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
      $("#buyusd").val(total1);

      var ngntotal = isNaN(parseInt(total1 * ngnrate)) ? 0 : (total1 * ngnrate);
      ngntotal1 = parseFloat(ngntotal).toFixed(2);
      $("#buyngn").val(ngntotal1);

    });

    var buyngn = $("#buyngn");
    buyngn.keyup(function() {
      var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyngn.val() / ngnrate)) ? 0 : (buyngn.val() / ngnrate);
      total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
      $("#buyusd").val(total1);

      var ghctotal = isNaN(parseInt(total1 * rate)) ? 0 : (total1 * rate);
      ghctotal1 = parseFloat(ghctotal).toFixed(2);
      $("#buyghc").val(ghctotal1);
    });
    break;
} });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create two `functions`.

```js
 $('#buyselect').change(function() {

        var value = $('#buyselect').val();
    switch (value) {
      case 'btc':
        var rate = 4.7;
        var ngnrate = 5.7;

        var buyusd = $("#buyusd");
          var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyusd.val() * rate)) ? 0 : (buyusd.val() * rate);
          total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyghc").val(total1);

          var ngntotal = isNaN(parseInt(buyusd.val() * ngnrate)) ? 0 : (buyusd.val() * ngnrate);
          ngntotal1 = parseFloat(ngntotal).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyngn").val(ngntotal1);

        var buyghc = $("#buyghc");
          var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyghc.val() / rate)) ? 0 : (buyghc.val() / rate);
          total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyusd").val(total1);

          var ngntotal = isNaN(parseInt(total1 * ngnrate)) ? 0 : (total1 * ngnrate);
          ngntotal1 = parseFloat(ngntotal).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyngn").val(ngntotal1);

        var buyngn = $("#buyngn");
          var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyngn.val() / ngnrate)) ? 0 : (buyngn.val() / ngnrate);
          total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyusd").val(total1);

          var ghctotal = isNaN(parseInt(total1 * rate)) ? 0 : (total1 * rate);
          ghctotal1 = parseFloat(ghctotal).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyghc").val(ghctotal1);
        break;

      case 'gcr':
        var rate = 7;
        var ngnrate = 3;

        var buyusd = $("#buyusd");
          var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyusd.val() * rate)) ? 0 : (buyusd.val() * rate);
          total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyghc").val(total1);

          var ngntotal = isNaN(parseInt(buyusd.val() * ngnrate)) ? 0 : (buyusd.val() * ngnrate);
          ngntotal1 = parseFloat(ngntotal).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyngn").val(ngntotal1);

        var buyghc = $("#buyghc");
          var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyghc.val() / rate)) ? 0 : (buyghc.val() / rate);
          total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyusd").val(total1);

          var ngntotal = isNaN(parseInt(total1 * ngnrate)) ? 0 : (total1 * ngnrate);
          ngntotal1 = parseFloat(ngntotal).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyngn").val(ngntotal1);

        var buyngn = $("#buyngn");
          var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyngn.val() / ngnrate)) ? 0 : (buyngn.val() / ngnrate);
          total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyusd").val(total1);

          var ghctotal = isNaN(parseInt(total1 * rate)) ? 0 : (total1 * rate);
          ghctotal1 = parseFloat(ghctotal).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyghc").val(ghctotal1);
        break;
    }
  });
     function change_value(){
    var value = $('#buyselect').val();
    switch (value) {
      case 'btc':
        var rate = 4.7;
        var ngnrate = 5.7;

        var buyusd = $("#buyusd");
        buyusd.keyup(function() {
          var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyusd.val() * rate)) ? 0 : (buyusd.val() * rate);
          total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyghc").val(total1);

          var ngntotal = isNaN(parseInt(buyusd.val() * ngnrate)) ? 0 : (buyusd.val() * ngnrate);
          ngntotal1 = parseFloat(ngntotal).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyngn").val(ngntotal1);
        });

        var buyghc = $("#buyghc");
        buyghc.keyup(function() {
          var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyghc.val() / rate)) ? 0 : (buyghc.val() / rate);
          total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyusd").val(total1);

          var ngntotal = isNaN(parseInt(total1 * ngnrate)) ? 0 : (total1 * ngnrate);
          ngntotal1 = parseFloat(ngntotal).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyngn").val(ngntotal1);

        });

        var buyngn = $("#buyngn");
        buyngn.keyup(function() {
          var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyngn.val() / ngnrate)) ? 0 : (buyngn.val() / ngnrate);
          total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyusd").val(total1);

          var ghctotal = isNaN(parseInt(total1 * rate)) ? 0 : (total1 * rate);
          ghctotal1 = parseFloat(ghctotal).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyghc").val(ghctotal1);
        });
        break;

      case 'gcr':
        var rate = 7;
        var ngnrate = 3;

        var buyusd = $("#buyusd");
        buyusd.keyup(function() {
          var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyusd.val() * rate)) ? 0 : (buyusd.val() * rate);
          total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyghc").val(total1);

          var ngntotal = isNaN(parseInt(buyusd.val() * ngnrate)) ? 0 : (buyusd.val() * ngnrate);
          ngntotal1 = parseFloat(ngntotal).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyngn").val(ngntotal1);
        });

        var buyghc = $("#buyghc");
        buyghc.keyup(function() {
          var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyghc.val() / rate)) ? 0 : (buyghc.val() / rate);
          total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyusd").val(total1);

          var ngntotal = isNaN(parseInt(total1 * ngnrate)) ? 0 : (total1 * ngnrate);
          ngntotal1 = parseFloat(ngntotal).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyngn").val(ngntotal1);

        });

        var buyngn = $("#buyngn");
        buyngn.keyup(function() {
          var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyngn.val() / ngnrate)) ? 0 : (buyngn.val() / ngnrate);
          total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyusd").val(total1);

          var ghctotal = isNaN(parseInt(total1 * rate)) ? 0 : (total1 * rate);
          ghctotal1 = parseFloat(ghctotal).toFixed(2);
          $("#buyghc").val(ghctotal1);
        });
        break;
    }
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" id="buyselect">
  <option> </option>
  <option value="btc">BITCOIN</option>
  <option value="gcr">GCR COIN</option>
</select>

<div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="amount">Amount in USD:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="buyusd" onkeypress="return change_value()">
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="amount">Amount in GHC:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="buyghc">
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="amount">Amount in NGN:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="buyngn">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: on page refresh the first keyup does not take effect but the second and afterwards does.

Comment: when i start typing lets say 34, the 3 wont calculate but after typing in the 4 in does the calc. but afterwards any single number calculates

Comment: but its working great just wanted to if know there is a fix for that. wont be a problem because my form requires min value of 10.

Answer (score 0):

create a common function  and call that function in onchange and onkey up 
codepen link https://codepen.io/kalaiselvan/pen/KqMPaK

```
      $(function(){
   $("#buyusd").keyup(function(){
       calculate();
   })
   $('#buyselect').change(function() {
        calculate();  
   }) 
});
function calculate(){
  var value = $("#buyselect").val();
     switch (value) {
          case 'btc':
            var rate = 4.7;
            var ngnrate = 5.7;

            var buyusd = $("#buyusd");

              var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyusd.val() * rate)) ? 0 : (buyusd.val() * rate);
              total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
              $("#buyghc").val(total1);

              var ngntotal = isNaN(parseInt(buyusd.val() * ngnrate)) ? 0 : (buyusd.val() * ngnrate);
              ngntotal1 = parseFloat(ngntotal).toFixed(2);
              $("#buyngn").val(ngntotal1);


              var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyghc.val() / rate)) ? 0 : (buyghc.val() / rate);
              total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
              $("#buyusd").val(total1);

              var ngntotal = isNaN(parseInt(total1 * ngnrate)) ? 0 : (total1 * ngnrate);
              ngntotal1 = parseFloat(ngntotal).toFixed(2);
              $("#buyngn").val(ngntotal1);

              var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyngn.val() / ngnrate)) ? 0 : (buyngn.val() / ngnrate);
              total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
              $("#buyusd").val(total1);

              var ghctotal = isNaN(parseInt(total1 * rate)) ? 0 : (total1 * rate);
              ghctotal1 = parseFloat(ghctotal).toFixed(2);
              $("#buyghc").val(ghctotal1);
            break;

          case 'gcr':
            var rate = 7;
            var ngnrate = 3;

            var buyusd = $("#buyusd");

              var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyusd.val() * rate)) ? 0 : (buyusd.val() * rate);
              total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
              $("#buyghc").val(total1);

              var ngntotal = isNaN(parseInt(buyusd.val() * ngnrate)) ? 0 : (buyusd.val() * ngnrate);
              ngntotal1 = parseFloat(ngntotal).toFixed(2);
              $("#buyngn").val(ngntotal1);



              var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyghc.val() / rate)) ? 0 : (buyghc.val() / rate);
              total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
              $("#buyusd").val(total1);

              var ngntotal = isNaN(parseInt(total1 * ngnrate)) ? 0 : (total1 * ngnrate);
              ngntotal1 = parseFloat(ngntotal).toFixed(2);
              $("#buyngn").val(ngntotal1);


              var total = isNaN(parseInt(buyngn.val() / ngnrate)) ? 0 : (buyngn.val() / ngnrate);
              total1 = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
              $("#buyusd").val(total1);

              var ghctotal = isNaN(parseInt(total1 * rate)) ? 0 : (total1 * rate);
              ghctotal1 = parseFloat(ghctotal).toFixed(2);
              $("#buyghc").val(ghctotal1);

            break;
        }

 }
```